# Why does an empty list that is passed to a razor view in ASP.NET MVC Core become null?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Imagine a controller action like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Ask()
{
    ...
    ViewData["MyItems"] = Enumerable.Empty<MyItem>();
    return View();
}
```

And a view like:

```
@{
    var myItems = ViewData["MyItems"] as IEnumerable<MyItem>
}

@foreach (var item in myItems) <-- this throws null reference exception
{
     <div>@item.SomeProp</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the following import statement to my view (or to _ViewImports.cshtml) that provides the `IEnumerable`:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic;
```

I am using Visual Studio Code and it does not have intellisense on Razor views to warn me about it. You be careful out there; Razor views without intellisense is like walking in a cemetery at night!